# What's the appropriate verb to use for people driving into a city?

Tags: word-choice

I'm not sure what verb to use to refer to people who are crossing the limits of a city entering it.
consider this example:

> "I want to send an automated message to all the drivers crossing my city border, entering it."

is it correct to use the word, **enter** here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can "enter" a city, but you can do so on foot, by train, by plane, in a car, on a horse, etc.  "Enter" is not limited to a specific mode of transportation.

If you want to talk specifically about people *driving* as they enter the city, then use "drive into".

> They **drove into** the city at night, the front windshield ablaze with bright lights and empty promises.